# How do ring homomorphism R → ℤ correspond to prime ideals of R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

In "Category Theory" (Oxford Logic Guides, 2010 by Steve Awodey), pg 35, Awodey makes an off-hand comment:

"Ring homomorphisms A → ℤ into the initial ring ℤ ... correspond to so-called prime ideals, which are the ring-theoretic generalizations of ultrafilters."

I can find other sources that claim this to be true, that "clearly" prime ideals of a ring correspond to its homomorphisms into ℤ. I understand both of these concepts individually and I'm trying to construct a proof connecting them using the homomorphism law alone, but I'm getting stuck.

How do you get from "homomorphism into ℤ" to "prime ideal"?

Comment: Hint: let $f\colon A\to \mathbb Z$ be an homomorphism. What can you say about $\ker f$?

Comment: What is $A$ here? Is it a special kind of thing, or just a generic commutative ring? Or a possibly noncommutative ring? (and I assume you are adopting the convention where the multiplicative unit is part of the structure of a ring?)

Comment: Inferring from the surrounding context, A is meant to be a commutative ring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what additional assumptions you're working under, but here is something that you can say:

> For a commutative ring $R$, the prime ideals are exactly the kernels of homomorphisms of $R$ into integral domains.

This is immediate if you now the First Isomorphism Theorem and the fact that $A/I$ is a domain iff $I$ is a prime ideal of $A$.

Now, the kernels of homomorphisms into $\mathbb Z$ certainly correspond to *some* prime ideals, but definitely not all, and that was not really 100% transparent in the passage you quoted. For example, the field of two elements has a prime ideal that does not correspond to any homomorphism into $\mathbb Z$, and the same can be said for $A=\mathbb C$, or any field for that matter.

Comment: He says "initial ring" as if to comment that it's not a coincidence. He does show that ultrafilters on a Boolean algebra corresponding to Boolean homomorphisms into the initial such algebra 2 follows from the fact that 2 is initial.

Comment: OK, might just be a red herring then.

Answer (score 5):

The claim is nonsensical:
There are plenty of prime ideals in $A=\mathbb C[X]$ but no ring morphism at all $\mathbb C[X]\to \mathbb Z$.
Worse still: there is only one ring  morphism $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ but infinitely many prime ideals $\mathbb Z$, as proved by Euclid.
The claim is also false for every field and even for every algebra over a field!
Actually, offhand I don't know a single ring for which the claim is true, but I'm not going to waste one nanosecond looking for one...

Comment: Since I have a nanosecond to waste: An example of a ring for which it is true is the zero ring.  But that's the only example, because if there is a homomorphism $A\to\mathbb{Z}$, there is also a homomorphism $A\to\mathbb{Z}/p$ for any prime $p$ and the kernels of these will be prime ideals that can't be obtained from homomorphisms $A\to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for your well-spent nanosecond, @Eric : +1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg The claim is not that there is a *bijective* correspondence, but just that there is *a* correspondence; every ring homomorphism to $\Bbb{Z}$ does correspond to a prime ideal. The phrasing is awkward and confusing though.

Comment: @Servaes Sure, but what confused me is that usually when one says "there is a (not necessarily bijective) correspondence" between two things, one expects maps going both ways!